# TypeError: Cannot read property 'book' of undefined at BookDetails.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to grab data from renderList and trying to use that data on render().
When I console.log

> this.renderList()

[image]

Above is the data I get back.

So on the render()
I tried console.log

> console.log(this.renderList()[0].book);

The above code throws

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'book' of undefined at BookDetails.render

So it seems like book is not defined in render() not sure how you can define the book property to render().

```
renderList() {
      return this.props.list.map((list) => {
        console.log("list", list.book_id);
        console.log("params", this.props.params.id)
        if(list.book_id === parseInt(this.props.params.id)) {
            console.log("true");
            return {
                    book: list.book_id
                }
            }
    })
}
render() {
    const {post} = this.props;
    const {user} = this.props;
    const {list} = this.props;
    const data= this.renderList()[0].list;

    if(!post) {
       return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    if(user) {
        console.log(this.renderList());
        console.log(this.renderList()[0].book);
       return (
           <div>
                <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
                <h2>Pages: {post.pages}</h2>
                <div>Reviews:</div>
                 <button 
                    onClick={() => { this.props.addToMyPage(
                        {
                            userId: user.user.user_id, 
                            bookId: post.book_id
                        }
                        )}}>
                    Add this to my page
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: is this data loading async? it could be that it doesn't exist at first and then renders afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things I would recommend.

**First** your renderList method is using a map but not returning every time. which can leave undefined in your returned map.

```
renderList() {
    const elems = [];
    const urlId = parseInt(this.props.params.id);
    this.props.list.forEach((list) => {
        console.log("list", list.book_id);
        console.log("params", this.props.params.id)
        if(list.book_id === urlId) {
            console.log("true");
            elems.push({
                book: list.book_id
            })
        }
    })
    return elems;
}
```

**Second** verify that this data is actually there initially. it could be that the data hasn't loaded and you are trying to access something before its actually come in.

**Third** you should use a helper method to get the values when searching over multiple nested objects to remove JS Exceptions. I use lodash for this.

```
const renderList = this.renderList();
_.get(renderList, '[0].book');
```

I would **HIGHLY** recommend you use something like the Lodash get method to get a value from something that could throw a js error.

**Fourth** you should make sure you have a list before calling render list

```
if(user && list) {
    const renderList = this.renderList();
    console.log(_.get(renderList, '[0].book'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Learned a lot from this.  @JohnRuddell One thing I don't get though is when should you use map over forEach?

Comment: @Yh1234 a map returns a value for every item in an array. so when you want to render every item in an array into a react component use a map. if you dont return something from your map then undefined is inserted into the array. so it would look like this `[undefined, undefined, {... data here}, undefined]` when you have logic like only matching the `props.params.id` you want a forEach because you only want to render a subset of the array of items. which is why you use an elems array variable and push onto it when you want it.